# jQuery - append each element to own parent

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

i want append each **h2.widget-title** to **div.title** to own parent, but with my code it will append each h2 to both!

```
$('h2.widget-title').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('.title');
});
```

or

```
   var objsts = $('h2.widget-title');
    $.each(objsts, function () {
        $(this).appendTo('.title');
    });
```

neither not working...

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxr54/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.prev()`:

### DEMO jsFiddle

```
var objsts = $('h2.widget-title');
$.each(objsts, function () {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('.title'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
   var objsts = $('h2.widget-title');
    $.each(objsts, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).siblings('.title'));
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/wxr54/10/)**